# Is Blinky the only troll with six eyes?

Tags: trollhunters

I just finished watching Guillermo del Toro's trollhunters on netflix. About halfway through I started looking, but didn't see any trolls aside from Blinky who had six eyes. Are there any other examples of six eyed trolls?

[image: Blinkous "Blinky" Galadrigal]

Comment: Is it not "Trollhunters" (all one word)?

Comment: @Valorum You're right! Fixed.\

Comment: Is the 2016 necessary in the tag? Are there other Trollhunters out there?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trollhunter Unless there is a better way of describing it than year, the naming similarities are enough that I'd think it'd be helpful.

Comment: Hmm. That's Trollhunter (singular) not Trollhunters (plural). I see your point though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is at least one.

Spoiler ahead, obviously:

> Episode 14, Return of the Trollhunter:
>  
>  In the forge, after saving Claire, Jim get sucked into the void; the entire sequence ends with some upset statues of Trollhunters, the second one shown is the statue of a six eyed troll. You didn't ask for living examples, right? :-D

**Update**, spotted a **new** one. Spoiler, again, and pretty big too:

> Blinkus' brother appears in the second season, and it/he has the same eyes configuration of its/his brother

Answer (score 1):

The original concept art for the show would suggest that there's at least one other six-eyed troll. It may not be what you had in mind, though...

[image]